# How to import an audio file from computer and import it to the <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am a new website learner. So i was making a website based on my father's request and i need to make a button that imports an audio to the  tag. There will also be an X button right next to it, but i dont know how to script that, theres also a table for the audio to be in. I've already made the import button, but not the whole thing. Heres a concept of what im actually trying to say:[concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL8Ti.png)

forgot to say, there will also be a keybind button that detects whatever key youre pressing then sets the keybind for it, but thats optional.

Here is my current script.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" accept=".ogg,.wav,.aiff,.mp3,.aac,.flac,.alac,.dsd,.pcm" />
    <button type="button" id="custom-button">CHOOSE A FILE</button>
    <span id="custom-text">No file chosen, yet.</span>
  </form>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-button {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #009578;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

#custom-button:hover{
    background-color: #00b28f;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

#custom-text {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

JS:

```
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    realFileBtn.click();
});

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (realFileBtn.value) {
        customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
    } else {
        customTxt.innerHTML = "no file chosen, yet.";
    }
})
```

i tried nothing as i dont know how to make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add an audio tag to your html

```html
<audio id="audio" controls"></audio>
```

add the following to your js

to get the file use realFileBtn.files[0], then create an url to your file by using window.URL.createObjectURL and set to src of your audio tag to that url

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (realFileBtn.value) {
        customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
        audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(realFileBtn.files[0]);
    } else {
        customTxt.innerHTML = "no file chosen, yet.";
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to make multiple buttons instead of one? Ive tried copy paste, but the first one only works as ids are unique and only selects the first element they see in the website (trying to solve the problem by searching on google and saw someone that had the same problem but a little bit different)

Comment: If you only have a few audio files i would suggest to just hardcode an unique id for each audio tag and file input tag. Otherwise use javascript to give each file input- audio tag a unique id.